# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -getValue: only defined for abstract class. Define -[KotlinInt getValue:]!'

Tags: swift, exception, kotlin, multiplatform

I am using Kotlin multiplatform to build framework for iOS, and everything works well except the strange issue.

The code from Kotlin:

```
fun example(): Map<Int, Double> {
        val result = mutableMapOf<Int, Double>()
        result[1] = 9.99
        return result
}
```

Using framework is Swift:

```swift
let example = example()
```

The app will crash and display the trace as following

```
2019-10-30 15:37:19.096474+0800 Test[73756:3057881] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -getValue: only defined for abstract class.  Define -[KotlinInt getValue:]!'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23baa1ee __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50864b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Foundation                          0x00007fff2584a6b3 _NSRequestConcreteObject + 0
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff256bea7e -[NSNumber copyWithZone:] + 129
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23add550 __NSSingleEntryDictionaryI_new + 128
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23ba56f3 -[NSDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 403
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c07fc7 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:] + 135
    7   libswiftFoundation.dylib            0x00007fff511ef3a0 $sSD10FoundationE26_forceBridgeFromObjectiveC_6resultySo12NSDictionaryC_SDyxq_GSgztFZ + 192
    8   libswiftFoundation.dylib            0x00007fff511e3593 $sSD10FoundationE36_unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveCySDyxq_GSo12NSDictionaryCSgFZ + 67
    9   Test                                0x0000000102f54320 $s4Test11ContentViewV3calSSyF + 1104
    10  Test                                0x0000000102f53e3b $s4Test11ContentViewV4bodyQrvg + 91
    11  Test                                0x0000000102f549c1 $s4Test11ContentViewV7SwiftUI0C0AadEP4body4BodyQzvgTW + 17
    12  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2bfb1c49 $s7SwiftUI8ViewBody33_9F92ACD17B554E8AB7D29ABB1E796415LLV5applyy0D0QzxF + 585
    13  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2bfb2df9 $s7SwiftUI8ViewBody33_9F92ACD17B554E8AB7D29ABB1E796415LLVyxG14AttributeGraph07UntypedM0AafGP7_update_5graph9attributeySv_So10AGGraphRefaSo11AGAttributeatFZTW + 137
    14  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff2f8f1849 $sTA + 25
    15  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff2f8d9255 _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 1111
    16  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff2f8d9513 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeEjb + 377
    17  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff2f8de131 _ZN2AG8Subgraph6updateEj + 929
    18  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c10d100 $s7SwiftUI9ViewGraphC14runTransaction33_D63C4EB7F2B205694B6515509E76E98BLL2inySo10AGGraphRefa_tF + 224
    19  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c10d517 $s7SwiftUI9ViewGraphC13updateOutputs2atyAA4TimeV_tFSb5prefs_Sb9idealSizeAC0F0V7outputstSo10AGGraphRefaXEfU_ + 103
    20  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c10d1d1 $s7SwiftUI9ViewGraphC13updateOutputs2atyAA4TimeV_tF + 145
    21  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c4af579 $s7SwiftUI16ViewRendererHostPAAE6render8interval17updateDisplayListySd_SbtFyyXEfU_yyXEfU_ + 1001
    22  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c4aef8a $s7SwiftUI16ViewRendererHostPAAE6render8interval17updateDisplayListySd_SbtFyyXEfU_ + 634
    23  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c4a4274 $s7SwiftUI16ViewRendererHostPAAE6render8interval17updateDisplayListySd_SbtF + 436
    24  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c65a182 $s7SwiftUI14_UIHostingViewC14layoutSubviewsyyF + 226
    25  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff2c65a1a5 $s7SwiftUI14_UIHostingViewC14layoutSubviewsyyFTo + 21
    26  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47a52ad5 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2478
    27  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b06e91d -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 255
    28  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b073323 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 517
    29  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b07fa7c _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 80
    30  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2afc6e54 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionEd + 324
    31  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2affc32f _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 643
    32  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff475906cd __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 81
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b0d09c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b0c808 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 312
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b07694 __CFRunLoopRun + 1284
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b06e66 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
    37  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff38346bb0 GSEventRunModal + 65
    38  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47578dd0 UIApplicationMain + 1621
    39  Test                                0x0000000102f526fb main + 75
    40  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff516ecd29 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Actually, I want to implement the function to return the Map, but I inspect the type of **example()** in the Xocde's IDE is [KotlinInt : KotlinDouble]. I don't know how to fix this to use this function in the Xcode normally without the exception.

Comment: Any progress on this issue? I'm facing the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I thought there is no structure type "Map" in Kotlin corresponding to "Dictionary" in iOS Swift. Try to replace the Map with MutableMap and solve this issue.

```
fun example(): MutableMap <Int, Double> {
        val result = mutableMapOf<Int, Double>()
        result[1] = 9.99
        return result
}
```

However, you can also cast the type in Swift for another using. For example,

```swift
let example = example() as! [Int64 : Double]
```

Answer (score 0):

Map exist in kotlin, here an example:

```
val map = mutableMapOf(1 to 1.2, 2 to 1.2, 3 to 1.5)
println(map)
map[4] = 3.4
println(map)
```

output:

```
{1=1.2, 2=1.2, 3=1.5}
{1=1.2, 2=1.2, 3=1.5, 4=3.4}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. But we're discussing the Kotlin-Multiplatform between kotlin and swift. If you'd like to using Map(Dictionary) in the swift, you should use MutableMap in the kotlin. Otherwise, you would face this issue as in the original post.